# How to Deal with Multiple Patterns in Financial Pattern Classification?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, data-science, recurrent-neural-network

I have a question regarding my project on financial pattern classification using deep learning. Currently, I have organized my data into sequences of 30 days, and within each 30-day sequence, there are multiple patterns. I'm uncertain about how to handle this situation, especially since I'm using the Ta library in Python.

Additionally, once I extract the patterns from each 30-day sequence, I'm unsure about how to label the data. Should I label it manually, or are there tools available to assist me in this process?

Could you please provide guidance on how to address these issues?

I still thinking about a solution since I wasn't expecting the problem to occur and especially this is my first time dealing with this problem